# What should I have if I've done everything?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm closing in on the end of Skyward Sword, it seems, and I'm wondering how I'll know that I've found everything.

If I've found everything unique or of limited quantity in the game, performed every sidequest and mastered every minigame, what should I have on my subscreen and in my Item Store? (I don't care so much about rupees and crafting material in Surface chests and as rewards for minigames, as they occur elsewhere.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going for a 100% playthrough of the game, here's what I've got.  I've played through the **Hero Mode** and gotten just about everything I possibly can AFAIK and defeated the final boss.  There is nothing else that I can do in the game except maybe find a few **Sheikah Stones** hiding off somewhere or some missing **Goddess Walls**.

#### WARNING: *SPOILERS* AHEAD

First of all in the **Collection** page of your inventory, you should have everything in the purple section checked off.

- You should have delivered **Cawlin's** letter.
- You should have done something about **Beedle's** missing bug.
- You should have retrieved the missing **Rattle**.
- You should have gotten all **Gratitude Crystals** (there's **80**) to **Batreaux** and turned him into a human.

Then in the main **Gear** page, here's everything starting from the left.

- You should have the **Master Sword** with all 3 flames:

  - Top: **Din's Flame**
  - Right: **Farore's Flame**
  - Left: **Nayru's Flame**
- You should have found all the **Pieces of Heart** in the game.  It should appear as a full heart and not empty or partially filled.  Without the **2 Life Medals** equipped, you should have **18 Hearts** at the end of the game for a grand total of **20 Hearts**.
- You should have the **Tycoon Wallet** given to you by **Batreaux** with **3 Extra Wallets** (giving **900 Rupee** capacity) purchased from **Beedle**.

- You should have **8 Dowsing** slots total with 6 of them filled:

  - Top-Left: **Rupees**
  - Top-Right: **Treasure**
  - Right: **Hearts**
  - Bottom-Right: **Goddess Cubes**
  - Bottom: **Look Around**
  - Bottom-Left: **Gratitude Crystals**
- You should have **8** slots available in your **Pouch**.
- You should have **8 Items** total in their upgraded forms:

  - Top-Left: **Gust Bellows**
  - Top: **Sacred Bow** (2 upgrades)
  - Top-Right: **Bomb Bag**
  - Right: **Tough Beetle** (2 upgrades)
  - Bottom-Right: **Big Bug Net** (1 upgrade)
  - Bottom: **Scattershot** (1 upgrade)
  - Bottom-Left: **Clawshots**
  - Left: **Whip**

- You should have the fully assembled **Triforce**.
- You should have the **Stone of Trials**.

- You should have the **Goddess Harp** with all **5** songs:

  - Top: **Song of the Hero**
  - Right: **Farore's Courage**
  - Bottom-Right: **Din's Power**
  - Bottom-Left: **Nayru's Wisdom**
  - Left: **Ballad of the Goddess**
- You should have the **Sailcloth**.
- You should have the **Water Dragon's Scale**.
- You should have the **Fireshield Earrings**.
- You should have the **Mogma Mitts**.

Finally, for the items:

- You should have **5 Bottles**.
- You should have a **Braced Shield** (2 upgrades)
- You should have a **Fortified Shield** (2 upgrades)
- You should have a **Goddess Shield** (2 upgrades)
- You should have the **Hylian Shield***
- You should have a **Large Seed Satchel**.
- You should have a **Large Bomb Bag**.
- You should have a **Large Quiver**.
- You should have **2 Life Medals**.
- You should have **2 Heart Medals**.
- You should have **2 Rupee Medals**.
- You should have **1 Treasure Medal**.
- You should have **1 Cursed Medal**.
- You should have **1 Potion Medal**.
- You should have **1 Bug Medal**.

<sub>* I actually don't have the **Hylian Shield**, getting it in **Hero Mode** is *TOUGH!*</sub>

Some other things worth noting:

- The **Goddess Statue** should now be on the surface at the **Sealed Grounds**.
- **Beedle's** shop should be completely sold out.
- You should see **Batreaux** in human form at the **Bazaar** during the day.
- The **Pumpkin Pull** should be available to you in front of the **Sparring Hall** after helping **Fledge**.
- **Dodoh's High Dive** should be available to you at **Fun Fun Island** after helping **Dodoh**.
- **Bug Heaven** should be available at **Bug Rock**.
- **Clean Cut** should be available at **Bamboo Island**.
- **Thrill Digger** should be available at **Eldin Volcano**.
- **Rickety Coaster** should be available at **Lanyru Desert** at the **Shipyard**.
- The **Thunder Dragon's Lighting Round** should be available at **Lanyru Desert** at the **Lanyru Gorge**.

That's about it.  I'm pretty sure this is everything there is in the game.

Answer (score 0):

It pays off to have 99 of all the treasures and bugs, as well as great highscores in all the different minigames (except Pumpkin Pull), and Boss Battles + Silent Realms.  All those things are carried over when you copy your file and start a new Hero Mode game from there.  Also you total playing time keeps adding up.